# css menu with diagonal border

Tags: css, menu, diagonal

I am creating a simple menu in CSS. The only "trick" is that I'd like diagonal left and right borders.
That's not really a problem though. Problem is that I need the first item of the menu to get a regular vertical border instead of a diagonal one.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Tutorials</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Snippets</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Articles</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Resources</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

and the CSS:

```
nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  color: #285064;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #12242d;
}
nav span {
  display: block;
}

@media all and (min-width: 690px) {
  nav li {
    margin: 0;
    transform: skewX(-10deg);
  }
  nav a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #285064;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #12242d;
  }
  nav span {
    transform: skewX(10deg);
  }
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle of the current menu:
http://jsfiddle.net/mfL8509t/

Basically on that example, I'd need the "home" container to get a vertical regular border on the left hand side only.

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Very easy, use `first-child` of

```
nav li:first-child {
  transform: inherit;
}
```

Comment: I just realised you want to only apply the the scew on the inside for the home. You would need to use `:before, after` to achieve this. However `scew` doesn't work on pysdeo elements.

Comment: Oh, nice one, I didn't know about first-child!
How can I make it work so only the left hand side border gets inherited and not the right one? Thanks!

Comment: Ye, this is a lot more difficult. I'm not even certain its possible, the way I would do it requires horrible looking code, div wrapped in other divs. The easiest way for me would be to use an image, but thats just as ugly :(

Comment: Ah crap!
Thanks a lot for your help anyway, much appreciated!